# Are my two samples independent enough for a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test?

Tags: r, independence, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have a set of polygons that correspond to home ranges of, say, 100 individuals for which I have measured the overlap between all possible pairs. This has given me a square matrix of dimensions 100x100. Let's say I want to divide these overlap values in two groups (A and B) and compare their distributions. Theoretically, my values would be in a matrix such as the one generated by the following R code, where A and B in the matrix indicate to which group the value in that cell would belong.

```
set.seed(123)
x <- matrix(sample(c("A", "B"), 5000, replace = T), ncol = 100, nrow = 100)`
```

With the following line I remove "values" from the lower triangle and the diagonal, to avoid duplicated values and the values of overlap of a polygon with itself: `x[lower.tri(x, diag = T)] <- NA`

My question is: are my two samples A and B independet "enough" for a K-S test given that, for instance, the value at cell `x[1,3]`, belonging to the group "A" is the overlap between polygon 1 and 3 and the value at cell `x[1,4]`, belonging to group "B" is the overlap between the same polygon 1 and another polygon, 4?

If, as I suspect, these two samples can't be considered independent, what would be an appropiate alternative way to test whether the two samples have different distributions?